# How to reduce the vertical space between text and equations in itemize lists?

Tags: spacing, amsmath, lists, itemize, vertical-spacing

I'm having a small vertical spacing problem with some itemize lists.  The vertical spacing between equations and the text above and under them is perfect, except in itemize lists, where the space is a bit too big.  I would like to reduce it a bit (but not too much).  Here's a MWE showing my issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla bla blablablablabla:
    \begin{equation}
        y = a x^2 + b x + c.
    \end{equation}
Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blabla bla.

\medskip

\begin{itemize}
    \item Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla blablabla blabla bla:
        \begin{equation*}
            y = x.
        \end{equation*}
    Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla blabla bla bla blabla.
    \medskip
    \item Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla blabla blabla bla bla bla:
            \begin{equation*}
                y \ne x.
            \end{equation*}
    Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla blabla blabla bla bla bla.
    \medskip
    \item Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla blabla blabla:
        \begin{equation*}
            y < x
        \end{equation*}
    Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla blabla blabla bla bla.
    \medskip
    \item Blablablabla:
        \begin{equation*}
            y > x.
        \end{equation*}
    Blabla blabla blabla bla bla blabla blabla blablabla.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

And here's a preview:

[image]

Currently, the vertical spacings appear to be very nice everywhere, but I believe there should be less vertical spaces around equations in some long itemize lists (especially since these equations are relatively simple and short, as this MWE shows).

So how could I reduce the vertical white space in the itemize list, without changing the normal current space for all the rest?  Or is that actually a good thing?

**EDIT:**  I was considering adding these commands *inside* the itemize environment :

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1ex}
```

I'm not sure this is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Those commands should work, but usually display math is flexible (default is 12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt), which makes your typeset output look nicer, so for choosing a size for the glue, you probably want to make it flexible (like `1ex minus .5ex plus .25ex` or similar)

Comment: @HoldenRohrer, then how would you modify the commands in my edit part?

Comment: Replace `1ex` in both lines with whatever glue you choose written in the same form as `1ex minus .5ex plus .25ex`

Comment: @HoldenRohrer, please, could you be more specific?  The command \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1ex minus .5ex plus .25ex} doesn't work.